# how to get top utilization process by mail using monit

Tags: monit

I would like to configure monit tool If CPU usage > 10% then send **top utilization process list by mail**. how to configure with monitrc file.

check process all_process
        if cpu usage > 10% then exec("ps -Ao user,uid,comm,pid,pcpu,tty --sort=-pcpu | head -n 6") result to mail then alert

Comment: Downvoting because you haven't shown any effort to solve your problem.

Comment: Andrew Schulman, I tried my best with the help of "monit help". so I though I don't want confuse who experience with this tool.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a very bad and chatty monitoring alert. I don't think it's effective to try to assess CPU utilization at the 10% threshold.

What are you *really* trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks Ewwhite for answering, I trying to configure e-mail alert for abnormal CPU utilization and long run process activity. so If I get process list when CPU reach beyond 10% it'll be helpful.

Comment: I able to receive CPU>10% report by mail using monit, and I would like to learn how to configure to get "top process" information by mail. Else if you have any other idea about my requirement let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure. You may have to script it.

Answer (score -2):

check process all_process if cpu usage > 10% then exec "/bin/bash -c 'ps -Ao user,uid,comm,pid,pcpu,tty --sort=-pcpu | head -n 6 | mail -s top admin@foo.bar'"

Comment: This needs a better explanation.